# Help with complex numbers geometry proof

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

See [this link](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/GeoGebra/FlankTriangles4.shtml).
The last step is skipped, because it is claimed to be trivial, but apparently there is a gap in my knowledge.

$M$ is $\frac{1}{2}(b+c)$ and $H$ is $\frac{1}{2}i(b+c)$, but how do you prove that $M$, $A$ and $H$ are collinear? (I assume that $A$ is $0$). I think that M rotated by $180^\circ$ (so multiplied by $-1$) must be H, however it this is not true..

Who can help me?

Comment: $H\ne\frac{1}{2}i(b+c)$. The diagram shows that the vector from E to G can be represented as $\frac{1}{2}i(b+c)$. You want that AM is perpendicular to EG, or that $\frac{1}{2}(b+c)$ is perpendicular to $\frac{1}{2}i(b+c)$, which should be obvious.

Comment: @almagest: I think that $EG$ is represented as $i(b+c)$.

Comment: @mathlove Good point! But what I said is otherwise correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $H$ is $\frac{1}{2}i(b+c)$

No, we don't have that $H$ is the midpoint of the line segment $EG$.

> I think that M rotated by $180^\circ$ (so multiplied by $-1$) must be H

No, we don't have that $AH=AM$.

All you need is to see that $AM\ (=(b+c)/2)$ is perpendicular to $EG\ (=i(b+c))$.

Comment: But why do we need that $AM\perp EG$ to prove that $M$, $A$ and $H$ are collinear? And how do we prove that $H$ is the midpoint of $EG$?

Comment: Think all is explained in my answer. However, H may or may not be the midpoint of EG, as explained previously. That is not part of the problem as posed at 'Cut-The-Knot'. You will need to read that again - carefully.

Comment: @rae306: For your first question, let $I$ be the intersection point between $AM$ and $EG$. Since $AH$ is an altitude in $\triangle{AEG}$, if we can prove that $AM\perp EG$, then this means that $I=H$, which implies that $H(=I),A,M$ are collinear. For your second question, $H$ is not necessarily the midpoint of $EG$, so you cannot prove that.

Comment: @rae306 Since you have a comprehensive answer it would be good accept it and close the question. This is customary on the website. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since line $AH$ is an altitude of $\Delta AEG$ it is perpendicular to side $EG$. Since point A is common to lines $MA$ and $AH$ it suffices to show that a vector in the direction of $MA$ is parallel to the altitude. This is achieved by showing that a line extending from $MA$ is also perpendicular to $EG$. This will also lead to the second result i.e. $EG = 2\cdot AM$.

Consider the vector, therefore in the direction $MA$.

Using capital letters, where the diagram uses lower case for vectors first note that $ - \mathop {AM}\limits^ \to   = \mathop {MA}\limits^ \to  $ and$$\mathop {MA}\limits^ \to   =  - \frac{{B + C}}{2} = {i^2}(\frac{{B + C}}{2})$$

But this is $$\frac{i}{2}(i(B + C))$$ so that $$\mathop {MA}\limits^ \to   = \frac{1}{2}\mathop {iEG}\limits^ \to  $$This shows that $\mathop {EG}\limits^ \to  $ is perpendicular to $\mathop {AM}\limits^ \to  $ since a factor $i$ effects a ${90^ \circ }$ rotation in the complex plane.

This shows that M, A and H must be collinear.

An added bonus is that we have also shown that $$\left| {\overrightarrow {MA} } \right| = \left| {\frac{1}{2}i\overrightarrow {EG} } \right| = \frac{1}{2}\left| {\overrightarrow {EG} } \right|$$ i.e.$$2 \cdot AM = EG$$

Any good?